# I am having trouble understanding custom theming

Tags: vmware-clarity

I've followed the examples in the docs and still cannot seem to get my custom theme to work. All I want to do is change the app background in the dark theme to something that isn't as...green. I removed CLR on my angular.json and imported it on styles.scss along with my custom theme sheet. The custom theme just has a root adjustment using CSS custom property of

```css
:root {
--clr-global-app-background: hsl(226, 30%, 14%);
}
```

I get a flash of my preferred background before the page fully renders and then it goes back to the default greenish grey default.